# Can't print "ñ" character to file when decoding a Base64 String

Tags: .net, vb.net, encoding, character-encoding, base64

I'm trying to make a CLI app to protect/unprotect text documents,
What I do is a easy 2 passes of Base64 encoding/decoding.

The problem begins when I try to encode documents which contains special characters as "ñ" "ç" or "áéíóú àèìòù äëïöü, the documents are in ANSI encoding, then when I decode the base64 string previously encoded I get a "?" character instead the original "ñ" character or the other latin chars.

I use the default ANSI encode to get the byte characters and to write the text file, I don't understand why I'm having trouble because If I try to encode/decode the "ñ" character in a msgbox just for testing then the decoded base64 string is printed as a "ñ" character good, maybe the problem is in the "List(Of String)" object who maybe stores bad the decoded strings?

How I can resolve this and make it more universal for character kinds?

This is the full source written in VS2012 targeting FW 4.0:

```
Module Main

#Region " Variables "

    ' Stores the file information
    Dim INFO As IO.FileInfo

    ' Stores the TextFile Content
    Private Content As String()

    ' Stores the Result Text
    Private Result As New List(Of String)

    ' Error messages
    Private ErrorMessages As New Dictionary(Of Integer, String) From { _
        {1, "Insuficient arguments"}, _
        {2, "Too many arguments"}, _
        {3, "File does not exist"}, _
        {4, "Unrecognized parametter. Valid parametters are: /P, /Protect, /U, /Unprotect"}}

    Dim Logo As String = <a><![CDATA[
 D""""""'DDD          CC'""""'cCC                              dP   
 D  dddd. `D          C' .ccc. `C                              88   
 D  DDDDD  D .d8888b. C  CCCCCccC 88d888b. dP    dP 88d888b. d8888P 
 D  DDDDD  D 88'  `88 C  CCCCCccC 88'  `88 88    88 88'  `88   88   
 D  dddd' .D 88.  .88 C. `ccc' .C 88       88.  .88 88.  .88   88   
 D       .DD `88888P' CC.     .dC dP       `8888P88 88Y888P'   dP   
 DDDDDDDDDDD          CCCCCCCCCCC               .88 88              
                                            d8888P  dP             
 By Elektro H@cker
]]></a>.Value



    Dim Syntax As String = <a><![CDATA[   

[+] Syntax:

    DoCrypt.exe [Switch] [TextFile]


[+] Switches:

    /P (or) /Protect   | Protect text file.
    /U (or) /Unprotect | Unprotect text file.


[+] Usage examples:

    # Protect file:
    DoCrypt.exe /P "Document.txt"

    # Unprotect file:
    DoCrypt.exe /U "Protected Document.txt"

]]></a>.Value

#End Region

    Sub Main()


        ' My.Computer.Clipboard.SetText(Encrypt_String("ñ"))
        ' MsgBox(Decrypt_String("OFE9PQ=="))

        Console.WriteLine(Logo)
        Parse_Arguments()
        Environment.Exit(0)
    End Sub

    ' Pase commandline arguments
    Private Sub Parse_Arguments()

        Select Case My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Count

            Case 0
                Help()

            Case Is < 2 ' Insuficcient arguments
                PrintError(1)

            Case Is > 2 ' Too many arguments
                PrintError(2)

            Case 2

                If Not IO.File.Exists(My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(1)) Then
                    PrintError(3)
                Else
                    INFO = New IO.FileInfo(My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(1))
                End If

                Try
                    Content = IO.File.ReadAllLines(INFO.FullName)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                End Try

        End Select

        Select Case My.Application.CommandLineArgs.Item(0).ToLower

            Case "/p", "/protect"

                For Each line As String In Content
                    Result.Add(Encrypt_String(line))
                    Console.WriteLine(Result.Last)
                Next

                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(INFO.Extension) Then
                    IO.File.WriteAllLines(String.Format("{0} Encrypted{1}", _
                                          INFO.FullName.Substring(0, INFO.FullName.LastIndexOf(".")), INFO.Extension), _
                                          Result, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
                Else
                    IO.File.WriteAllLines(INFO.FullName & " Encrypted.txt", Result, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
                End If

            Case "/u", "/unprotect"

                For Each line As String In Content
                    Result.Add(Decrypt_String(line))
                    Console.WriteLine(Result.Last)
                Next

                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(INFO.Extension) Then
                    IO.File.WriteAllLines(String.Format("{0} Decrypted{1}", _
                                          INFO.FullName.Substring(0, INFO.FullName.LastIndexOf(".")), INFO.Extension), _
                                          Result, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
                Else
                    IO.File.WriteAllLines(INFO.FullName & " Decrypted.txt", Result, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
                End If

            Case Else
                PrintError(4)

        End Select

        Environment.Exit(0)

    End Sub

    ' Prints Help syntax
    Private Sub Help()
        Console.WriteLine(Syntax)
        Environment.Exit(1)
    End Sub

    ' Prints An ErrorMessage
    Private Sub PrintError(ByVal Errormessage As Short)
        Console.WriteLine("[X] Error: " & ErrorMessages(Errormessage))
        Environment.Exit(1)
    End Sub

    ' Encrypt String
    Public Function Encrypt_String(ByVal str As String) As String
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes( _
               Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str))))
    End Function

    ' Decrypt String
    Private Function Decrypt_String(ByVal str As String) As String
        Return System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String( _
                System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(str))))
    End Function

End Module
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about the exact conditions under which you are testing this code, but it should work fine. The error you are referring is, most likely, provoked by having selected a wrong encoding method while reading/writing. In any case, with the default configuration and by using your code I don't find any problem:

```
Result.Add(Encrypt_String("ñ")) 'Result(0) = "OFE9PQ=="
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("file path", Result(0))
Dim out As String = Decrypt_String(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file path").Trim()) 'out = "ñ"
```

Please, tell the exact conditions under which you are having this problem.

**UPDATE**

When replacing the first line with `ReadAllText` (from a file where only "ñ" is written), I don't get anything (a blank string). I have to set the encoding to `Default` to make it work as above:

```
Result.Add(Encrypt_String(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("file path", System.Text.Encoding.Default).Trim()))
```

The name of the default encoding (`System.Text.Encoding.Default.EncodingName`) is `Western European (Windows)`.

Thus, it is a problem of choosing the right encoding while reading the file, rather than something with the .NET variables. The curious things is that **`ReadAllText` does not account by default for `Encoding.Default`** (!).

Comment: I think I've gived all the necessary things when asking, please tell me which exact conditions you need. The text files are in ANSI encoding (notepad > save > Ansi encoding) which is the same as system.text.encoding.default which are the same encoding I write and get the text, I'm on Windows 8 Core x64, Spanish language and keyboard distribution. I've tried to change string arrays to simple strings to use the methods "WriteAllText" and also without specifying the read/write encoding, I get the same null "?" character.

Comment: Please instead directly adding the "ñ" to the list like in your example try first to get the "ñ" from a textfile content in ANSI encoding and adding it to the list, then you will see what I'm saying, thanks for answer

Comment: @ElektroHacker clearer now. Please, take a look at my updated answer.